# CoreData Stops the saving after Heavyweight migration Xcode 14

Tags: swift, xcode, sqlite, core-data-migration

Due to the enhancement in my project, I have done the heavyweight migration, now after heavy weight migration, CoreData is unable to store data it always return empty.

I have a class Function

```
class func insert(object: [String: Any], entityName: String) -> NSManagedObject?    {
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: entityName, in: context)!
    let managedObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: context)

    let keys = Array(entity.attributesByName.keys)
    print("Keys:\(keys)\nobject:\(object)")
    for (key, element) in object  {
        if keys.contains(key)   {
            managedObject.setValue(element, forKey: key)
        }
    }
    do {
        print(managedObject.isUpdated)
        try context.save()
        print(managedObject.isUpdated)
        print("Success insert")
    } catch {
        print("Error in Insert: \(error)")
    }
    return managedObject
}
```

so I pass my Object with the key value pair in form of Dictionary, I pass the entityName to this function so it never return nil in `managedObject` While it always show false on `print(managedObject.isUpdated)` on both lines. Here is my console logs for saving data.

```
  Keys:["contactIdentifier", "timeAndDate", "receiverId", "createdAt", "updatedAt", "i-----------g", "se---d", "duration", "senderId", "number", "name", "isFromiOS", "opponentsIds", "m-------d"]
object:["sessionID": "E1ECAB27-D312", "message": "--------", "contactIdentifier": "------- ", "I----p": "1", "contactNumbers": "------------,-----------", "V-----l": "1", "co------pe": "2", "createdAt": 2022-10-27 11:58:18 +0000, "opponentsIds": "---, ----"]
false
false
Success insert
updateCallInformation:<CallHistory2: 0x2835e99f0> (entity: CallHistory2; id: 0xa46b7d533bd5d14b <x-coredata://BAF5AFD6-8567-4485-8938-E13D3BD7B314/CallHistory2/p1>; data: {
    contactIdentifier = "MDanishPK ";
    createdAt = "2022-10-27 11:58:18 +0000";
    duration = nil;
    incomingOutgoing = nil;
    isFromiOS = 0;
    missedReceived = nil;
    name = nil;
    number = nil;
    opponentsIds = nil;
    receiverId = nil;
    senderId = nil;
    sessionID = "E1ECAB27-D312-4402-91D3-87AEBAC1A709";
    timeAndDate = nil;
    updatedAt = nil;
})
```

In console ---- I added intentially here for the privacy. There are some proper values and keys here.

If I revert my migration and goto the older branch using git than its working fine and save data properly. But I need heavy weight migration which [I achieved using this article](https://shakya4577.medium.com/heavyweight-core-data-migration-51570555124b) Kindly help me out and guide me what I have to do To save managedObject? and what I am doing wrong in saving managedObject? I changed all the table name but still its not saving data. On every launch I also lost the data.

- Update Question

After Insert data I am using this fetch method, It always return me 0 against the array of `[NSManagedObject]?`

```
class func fetchList(entityName: String, predicate: NSPredicate? = nil, sortBy: [(key: String, ascending: Bool)]? = nil) ->
        
        [NSManagedObject]?  {
            let context = CoreDataStack.context
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: entityName)
            fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
            
            if let sortedBy = sortBy    {
                var sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor]()
                for sortElement in sortedBy   {
                    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: sortElement.key, ascending: sortElement.ascending)
                    sortDescriptors.append(sortDescriptor)
                }
                fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
            }
            
            do {
                let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
                return results
            }   catch   {
                print("Could not fetch: \(error)")
            }
            return nil
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn’t you be checking isInserted, rather than isUpdated for a new object?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I tried the isInserted, it return true before the try context.save
after that it returns false, after completion of this method I try to fetch from the entity and it returns nothing.

Comment: So the save works fine then. Have you runned this with core data debugging enabled? Have you used some SQLite tool to check whether something has been inserted in the corresponding table in the database? Are you sure the fetch request is correct? Sounds to me like you have some trouble shooting to do yourself before we can help you any further.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes I am sure the fetch request is correct, I am going to share the fetch method also in the question. I have one question on your suggestion. Will SQLite tool show us the iPhone table/Entity data?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, if you get a tool that works with SQLite and you use it correctly yes then it is going to show you the data you requested